# Use Session in Parent Folder in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have 2 folders/directories:

```
login/helper.php
dashboard/index.php
```

I have set a session in helper.php in the `login` folder. I am trying to retrieve a session on the index page in the `dashboard` folder. Somehow i cannot retrieve the session in another folder or a parent directory.

Here is the Code on the **login/helper.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userID'] = $checklogin['userID'];
```

Here is the code on the **dashboard/index.php**

```
echo $_SESSION['userID'];
```

Is there a way to make a session available in a parent directory and all it's folders?

Kind Regards

Comment: please provide the code where you set and retrive your session...

Comment: You have to initiate session by 
 
    session_start()

at every **entrypoint** of your site if you want session data.

Comment: look at [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) and set the `$path` param to `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start the session again in dashboard/index.php:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['userID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case looks like you need to add `session_start()` at the starting of your file.

But as per coding standards I would suggest to put that `session_start()` in a common file and may be try to include that file in your all pages, that way you don't need to include `session_start(0)` everywhere.